# HTML and plain text in same email

Tags: php, email, html-email

I'm building a PHP based newsletter application. I know it is a good practice to send plain text version of the email beside the html as well. My question is how can I do this in practice? Just simply put one under the other? like:

```
<p style="font-weight:bold;">This is a newsletter!</p>
<p style="color:red;">
   You can read awesome things here!
   <br/>
   <a href="www.the-awesome-site.com">check out us on the web!</a>
</p>

This is a newsletter\r\n
You can read awesome things here!\r\n
check out us on the web: www.the-awesome-site.com
```

Won't these two interfere with each other? I mean if the mailer client can understand HTML, then the plain text with nearly the same content would be confusing at the end of the mail. Or if the client can't parse html then the user will see bothering raw HTML source before the human friendly plain text. Is there any way hide the useless one depending on the situation? I'm going to use PHPMailer if it is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHPMailer is a great class to use because it detects when the email client doesn't support HTML.

```
Check out this code snippet. It should help a little.

require("PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "mail.somemailserver.com";  
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;


$mail->From = $someemail;
$mail->FromName = "Who ever";
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->AddCC($anotheremail);

$mail->WordWrap = 50;



$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Some subject";

$mail->Body    = "<html>Content goes here</html>";


//if the client doesn't support html email use
$mail->AltBody = "Content";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
```

By using the $mail->AltBody, you can send plain text emails. Hope this helps!

Comment: Good one, I am using the same